# Android - problems using FragmentActivity + Loader to update FragmentStatePagerAdapter

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I'm trying to use `FragmentActivity` with `ViewPager` to display dynamic list of `Fragments`. There are plenty of examples on how to do a static version of it. My problem is that the list I display needs to be loaded dynamically and also can change based on user input (add/delete). I'm trying to use customized `android.support.v4.content.Loader` to load set of data that I can use to build my list.

Everything goes fine in my setup until I get to the point when I want to update the adapter and issue `FragmentStatePagerAdapter#notifyDataSetChanged()` call at which point this code is executed (from `FragmentStatePagerAdapter`)

```
public void finishUpdate(View container)
{
    if(mCurTransaction != null)
    {
        mCurTransaction.commit(); // BANG!!! The exception is thrown
        mCurTransaction = null;
        mFragmentManager.executePendingTransactions();
    }
}
```

The transaction commit fails with this message:

`java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can not perform this action inside of onLoadFinished`

because within `FragmentManagerImpl` this code is executed:

```
private void checkStateLoss() {
    if (mStateSaved) {
        throw new IllegalStateException(
                "Can not perform this action after onSaveInstanceState");
    }
    if (mNoTransactionsBecause != null) {
        throw new IllegalStateException(
                "Can not perform this action inside of " + mNoTransactionsBecause);
    }
}
```

It turns out that `mNoTransactionsBecause` value is not null and it is set in `LoaderManagerImpl.LoaderInfo` when the result is returned back to `onLoadFinished`

I was looking at the various variables trying to somehow change `tramsaction.commit()` to `transaction.commitAllowingStateLoss()` but everything related to transaction seems to be private or at least package-protected.

Can someone give me a general idea if I can do what I need to do (and how)?

Just to note that my code works fine if instead of using Loader I run the loading ops in AsyncTask

Comment: Have you been able to figure out the proper way to do this with a Loader? I'm facing the same problem. I was able to get it to work using `transaction.commitAllowingStateLoss()`, but it would still be nice to know what Google intended us to do...it seems like there should be a way to perform a fragment transaction after loading data using a Loader...

Comment: I generally gave up on this and am using ModernTaskLoader with limited pooling

Comment: What is ModernTaskLoader? Couldn't find any information about it anywhere...

Comment: This is from compatibility package v4

Comment: Hmm...the only two loaders I see in the support package are AsyncTaskLoader and CursorLoader :/

Comment: Correction: android.support.v4.content.ModernAsyncTask.ModernAsyncTask

Comment: Ah, I see it now, thanks. It's not a public class, so it's not showing up in the official documentation.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

I had a very similar problem to this and solved it by using a handler on the Fragment.

I wanted to show an alert dialog on onLoadFinished(), similar to the following

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment 
    implements LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<T> {

    public void onLoadFinished(Loader<T> loader, T data) {
        showDialog();
    }

    public void showDialog() {
        MyAlertDialogFragment fragment = new MyAlertDialogFragment();
        fragment.show(getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager(), "dialog");

    }
}
```

But this gave an error

**can not perform this action inside of onLoadFinished**

The solution was to add a handler to the fragment to take care of showing the dialog

```
private Handler handler = new Handler() {
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        if(msg.what == MSG_SHOW_DIALOG) {
            showDialog();
        }
    }
};
```

And then modify onLoadFinished(...) to send a message to the handler instead

```
   public void onLoadFinished(Loader<T> loader, T data) {
        handler.sendEmptyMessage(MSG_SHOW_DIALOG);
    }
```

Comment: Or you post a runnable onto the handler.
`Handler h = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
h.post(new Runnable(){ .... });` etc

Comment: @Chris.Jenkins Ian's implementation is more efficient because it only requires a single object allocation. :)

Comment: @AlexLockwood Not really an issue unless you are creating 1000's of objects in one hit in a high performance scenario.

Comment: Also, note that this solution only avoids the exception. It doesn't actually prevent fragment state from being lost. If `onLoadFinished()` is called, the runnable is posted, and the `DialogFragment#show()` code is executed after `onSaveInstanceState()` has been called (which would be rare, but probably still possible), then the `DialogFragment`'s state will not be remembered when the `Activity`'s state is later restored. In general, you probably want to avoid showing dialogs in `onLoadFinished()` (it's bad for the user experience anyway).

Comment: Just a heads up! This works with `FragmentStatePagerAdapter` and does not work with `FragmentPagerAdapter`. Luckily OP was using the right one. But I had to spent some hours on this.

Comment: This actually makes things worse! the Loader has gone to the trouble of calling onLoadFinished on the correct instance of fragment. Then you have implicitly referenced that instance through `handler.sendEmptyMessage();`. Between sending that message and it being handled, your Fragment/Activity may be destroyed due to a config change and you'll end up running this on the wrong instance. Basically you're better off using commitAllowingStateLoss

Answer (score 0):

You can copy `FragmentStatePagerAdapter` and change it however you like, or create your own `PagerAdapter` from scratch. Or simply don't use a Loader.

Comment: This is not problem with adapter, all it is doing - committing the transaction. But someone went to considerable effort to prevent transaction commits in onLoadFinished. I want to know why? I also don't like rewriting classes for the sake of a single line And I do like Loader concept and want to use it. As I stated - I do have  working implementation directly using AsyncTask

Comment: Apparently because there is some possibility of state loss when calling in `onLoadFinished()`. From the JavaDoc: 'Note that normally an application is not allowed to commit fragment transactions while in this call, since it can happen after an activity's state is saved. See FragmentManager.openTransaction() for further discussion on this. ' You have to either change to adapter to use `commitAllowingStateLoss()` or scrap the loader. I had the same problem, and here's the answer I got: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-developers/dXZZjhRjkMk/discussion

Answer (score 0):

It works using rootView.post(). Just define rootView variable in class scope and then inflate it onCreateView(). 
Finally onLoadFinished() simply use it like this:

```
            rootView.post(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    General.showFragment();
                }

            });
```