# changing fragment in CursorLoader onLoadFinished() method?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-cursorloader

I am trying to change fragment in `OnLoadFinished()` method of `CursorLoader` but I am getting following exception:

```
0-15 13:16:35.565      265-293/system_process E/Lights﹕ write_int failed to open sys/class/leds/rk29_key_led/brightness
10-15 13:19:12.265    4998-4998/com.mobiotics.tvb_stb E/Trace﹕ error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
10-15 13:19:12.845    4998-4998/com.mobiotics.tvb_stb E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can not perform this action inside of onLoadFinished
            at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.checkStateLoss(FragmentManager.java:1284)
            at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.enqueueAction(FragmentManager.java:1291)
            at android.app.BackStackRecord.commitInternal(BackStackRecord.java:548)
            at android.app.BackStackRecord.commit(BackStackRecord.java:532)
            at com.mobiotics.tvb_stb.activity.HomeScreenActivity.OnChannelCountChanged(HomeScreenActivity.java:308)
            at com.mobiotics.tvb_stb.fragments.ChannelDBThumbFragment.onLoadFinished(ChannelDBThumbFragment.java:234)
            at com.mobiotics.tvb_stb.fragments.ChannelDBThumbFragment.onLoadFinished(ChannelDBThumbFragment.java:44)
            at android.app.LoaderManagerImpl$LoaderInfo.callOnLoadFinished(LoaderManager.java:482)
            at android.app.LoaderManagerImpl$LoaderInfo.onLoadComplete(LoaderManager.java:450)
            at android.content.Loader.deliverResult(Loader.java:143)
            at android.content.CursorLoader.deliverResult(CursorLoader.java:113)
            at android.content.CursorLoader.deliverResult(CursorLoader.java:43)
            at android.content.AsyncTaskLoader.dispatchOnLoadComplete(AsyncTaskLoader.java:254)
            at android.content.AsyncTaskLoader$LoadTask.onPostExecute(AsyncTaskLoader.java:91)
            at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:631)
            at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:644)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Help me figuring out what I am doing wrong here!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12276243/commit-fragment-from-onloadfinished-within-activity

Comment: What exactly are you doing in `onLoadFinished`?

Comment: i have implemented a callback method to change the fragment i am calling that method in OnLoadFinished() method